# Custom style on product page in Pinnacle Cart

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, pinnacle-cart

I'm trying to add a custom style on a [product page](https://support.pinnaclecart.com/hc/en-us/articles/204031028-Adding-a-Product) in the [Pinnacle Cart](https://www.pinnaclecart.com/) CMS. I've tried adding a `<style>` tag through the `Source Code` button in the content editor. Yet, it seems that `<style>` tags get destroyed by the CMS once you save your page. I'm not sure how else to inject custom CSS into a product page.

The only *possible* alternative that I see is that maybe I could apply the CSS globally, though [the CSS system in Pinnacle Cart.](https://support.pinnaclecart.com/hc/en-us/articles/215190777) Unfortunately, that could obviously cause problems in other pages wherein the CSS may apply to elements for which it is not intended.

EDIT:

I have also tried the following: going to "Cart Designer" for my site, going to the page in question, clicking on Advanced Tools, and then clicking "Edit custom css". However, when I do that, it seems that the CSS is not saved properly. If I check the custom CSS for that page, it shows up in the source editor. However, the custom stylesheet with my rules does not get served by the server when I request the page.